# How to pass value in a function on click, Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have this button that should pass the value of a field, Page on click event to this function SelectPage in my JS. Any idea why it is not working?I am getting a null as input to the function.

```
<button data-bind="click: $root.selectPage.bind($root, $root.rootData.Page())" id="gotoBtn" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
```

Comment: Please provide working fiddle that reproduces your problem.

Comment: ah, can not create fiddel, something wrong on my network, i can only access certain website. Network problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html, note 2:

```
<button data-bind="click: function(data, event) { myFunction('param1', 'param2', data, event) }">
    Click me
</button>
```

You need to wrap your function call to pass in params

Edit: your function, updated

```
<button data-bind="click: function(){$root.selectPage.bind($root, $root.rootData.Page());}" id="gotoBtn" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my issue, one more question: Why the value is not updating <input data-bind="value: $root.rootData.Page()" id=" gotoinput" class="form-control" placeholder="Jump to ...">

Comment: without seeing the viewmodel or any code, I can't say.